# SwuiftUI Custom Sorting

Tags: ios, sorting, struct, swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm just starting out in SwuiftUI so bear with me.
I have a Game stuct that has a field lastUpdated and title. I want to have the choice to sort by my list by lastUpdated or title. But I'm not sure how this works. I've looked into sorted(by:) but I can't really get anything to work. Suggestions?

```
struct Game: Identifiable, Codable {
let id: UUID
var title: String
var players: [Player]
var lastUsed: Date }
```

GameView

```
struct GameListView: View {
@Binding var games: [Game]
    
var body: some View {
    
    List {
        ForEach($games) { $game in
            NavigationLink(destination: GameView(game: $game)) {
                Text(game.title)}
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scenario is slightly complicated by the `Binding` form of `ForEach`, but you should still be able to return a sorted collection. It might look like this:

```
struct GameListView: View {
    @Binding var games: [Game]
    @State var sortType : SortType = .lastUsed
    
    enum SortType {
        case lastUsed, title
    }
    
    var sortedGames : [Binding<Game>] {
        $games.sorted(by: { a, b in
            switch sortType {
            case .lastUsed:
                return a.wrappedValue.lastUsed < b.wrappedValue.lastUsed
            case .title:
                return a.wrappedValue.title < b.wrappedValue.title
            }
        })
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(sortedGames) { $game in
                NavigationLink(destination: GameView(game: $game)) {
                    Text(game.title)}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this method works great, however, when I delete one of the rows, it gives me an error that "index is out of range" I'm really stumped. Adding rows or editing rows of game.player is no problem at all and it shows up great. Its only when i delete rows.

Comment: Interesting, but I’d have to see the method you’re using to delete it. Probably a good opportunity for a new question.